# How to input a list of integers in python 3.6.5?

Tags: python-3.6

1)L=list(input("Enter some values:"))

print(L)

```
**input:**54321

**Output:**['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

2)L=list(eval(input("Enter some values:")))

print(L)

```
 **Error:**TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

L = list(str(input("Enter some values:")))

print(L)

Comment: or for validation you can do like this :

L = input("Enter some values:")
print(list(str(L)))

Comment: Given the OP is using Python 3 per title and tags, this answer is the same as the OP's option "1" with an unnecessary `str` thrown in.  What's the value added?